# Parse Server Cloud Code destroyAll fails with unhelpful error

Tags: parse-cloud-code, parse-server

I am updating some previously working cloud code to the new Parse Server. I have updated it with the new method of passing useMasterKey.

The query part appears to be working as the resultingStations array gets populated, but the delete is failing.

```
Parse.Cloud.afterDelete("Workout", function(request) {

query = new Parse.Query("WorkoutStation");

query.equalTo("workout", request.object);

query.find({

    success: function(resultingStations) {

        console.log('Found these to delete:' + resultingStations);

        Parse.Object.destroyAll(resultingStations, {
            success: function() {
                console.log('Did successfully delete');
            },
        error: function(error) {
            console.error("Error deleting related workout stations " + error.code + ": " + error.message);
        }
        }, { useMasterKey: true });

    },

    error: function(error) {
        console.error("Error finding related workout stations " + error.code + ": " + error.message);
    }

}, { useMasterKey: true });
});
```

If I look in the dashboard the objects in resultingStations are still there, and in the server log I get the error:

"Error deleting related workout stations 600: undefined"

600 doesn't seem to be a valid error code.

[Error code list here](https://parseplatform.github.io/Parse-SDK-dotNET/api/html/T_Parse_ParseException_ErrorCode.htm)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the Parse.Error definitions on my local Parse Server (\node_modules\parse\lib\node\ParseError.js), code 600 indicates an Aggregate error as below:

```
    /**
 * Error code indicating that there were multiple errors. Aggregate errors
 * have an "errors" property, which is an array of error objects with more
 * detail about each error that occurred.
 * @property AGGREGATE_ERROR
 * @static
 * @final
 */
ParseError.AGGREGATE_ERROR = 600;
```

Which explains why `error.message` is undefined. `error.errors` should be an array of errors, which could give you some hints to what's going wrong.

As for the root cause, I have a feeling it might be to do with the use of useMasterKey. I migrated to using Promises quite a while ago, but if I remember correctly it should be something like this (for the destroyAll section):

```
Parse.Object.destroyAll(resultingStations, {
            success: function() {
                console.log('Did successfully delete');
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.error("Error deleting related workout stations " + error.code + ": " + error.message);
            },
            useMasterKey: true
        });
```

Comment: You nailed it, thanks! I guess I will have an issue with my implementation of useMasterKey for the query also, but in this specific case I was working with objects that are public read so didn't get an error.

Comment: its worth mentioning that a 600 error is not fatal, and you still get to destroy everything as expected. to access the errors you gotta check the error array ```error.errors```, which most likely are "object not found" errors, which is not a big deal breaker cause you wanted it gone anyways.